# append SQL database with data from txt file

Tags: azure, append, azure-sql-database, txt

Please assume I know nothing about this topic, because I really don't. I only know what I want to achieve.
Our webshop supplier gives me - every day- a deepdive file of all the user interactions on our webshop.
This file contains only the events from that specific day.
So I want to create a database which appends all historical files and the new files that come in every day in the future.

I already have SQL database via Azure Cloud where I would like to add a table.

The file names looks like this:

1. File of April 29th: DeepdiveData-20210429.txt
2. File of April 28th: DeepdiveData-20210428.txt
3. File of April 27th: DeepdiveData-20210427.txt

My question is:

How exactly do I automatically load this daily file and append it in the database (so I mean add the records in the database).

Please try to explain it like you would to a 6 year old :-).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which "SQL database"? SQL is a language, supported by many products.

Comment: Azure SQL database. Does that help?

Comment: Hi@Yanni Pattas Where are these files stored? Do you want to extract the contents of the new file into Azure sql when a new file is generated? Do you need any additional information, such as file name, etc.